# How do I access a cell's content that is outside of a filtered range in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

This code will go through a filtered range and insert only the visible cells into an array (pretend column A was filtered according to my criteria).  BUT, what I really want to do is shift one column over and insert the contents of "B3" into my array instead of "A3".  How do I modify my code to this?

```
For Each cell In Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Array1(i) = cell.Value
    i = i + 1
Next c
```

I was thinking something like Array1(i) = Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 1).Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each cell In Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Array1(i) = cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value
    i = i + 1
Next c
```

Comment: EXACTLY what I was looking for, thanks!  Offset...gotta remember that one.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each cell In Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   Array1(i) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
   i = i + 1

Next c
```

Answer (score 1):

Since column B is going to be subject to the same filter as Column A, here's a flexible solution that allows you to specify which column you want to use:

```
Sub FilterColumn(ColumnNumber As Long)
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngVisible As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Array1() As Variant
Dim i As Long

With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Columns(ColumnNumber)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColumnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngVisible = .Range(.Cells(2, ColumnNumber), .Cells(LastRow, ColumnNumber)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rngVisible Is Nothing Then
        ReDim Preserve Array1(1 To rngVisible.Cells.Count)
        i = 1
        For Each cell In rngVisible
            Array1(i) = cell.Value
            i = i + 1
        Next cell
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Call it like this for column B:

```
FilterColumn 2
```

As a side note, I'd suggest you don't use Excel reserved words for variable names.  Range is a reserved word.

Comment: Yikes, I appreciate the time spent writing this out for me, but Offset was all I really needed.  Thanks!